# Android action bar home button not including activity title

Tags: actionbarsherlock, android-actionbar-compat

I am using the home button of the main Activity of my IM app to allow the user to change their availability status. My app is using ActionBarSherlock, which falls back to the native implementation where supported.

However, the size of the tappable area is inconsistent between Android releases:

On Android 4.2.0 and before (including the compatibility library), only the icon is tappable:

[image: Android 4.1]

On Android 4.2.1+, *icon and activity name* are tappable:

[image: Android 4.2]

**How can I make the tappable area consistently include icon *and* activity title on all versions of Android?**

Answer (score 0):

I am using ActionBarCompat (and you should probably update, if you haven't already), so this may not behave exactly the same. I wanted the full title to be clickable for using the navigation drawer.  For some reason, using a custom logo instead of the text makes the whole thing automatically clickable, where only the icon could be clicked before:

```
final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
actionBar.setLogo(R.drawable.im_title);
```

I don't know if it's possible to trigger that change while still using text with the default icon, but the setDisplay... methods and flags may be a good place to start looking.

Comment: It looks like Logo and Item are equivalent, except for allowing of wider Logos. It does not make the title text clickable, and I do not want to make the title text an image for obvious reasons.

Comment: Makes sense... but the unfortunate thing may be that this is a bug (or change in behavior) that wasn't fixed until 4.2.1 and fixing it would require some hacking in ActionBarSHerlock / ActionBarCompat.  Best I can think of is having a transparent logo image, and a negative padding to ensure that the text starts at the left edge of the transparent image as if it wasn't there (except for click capture).  You may be able to find access to the padding/margins in ABS, but not ABS or the native implementation.